# Not able to unzip folder objective c

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, zip, unzip

I am using objective-zip for zip/unzip files within folder. my folder contains multiple images, sqlite db file etc. [This is the link from where i downloaded](https://github.com/AgileBits/objective-zip/tree/master/Objective-Zip)

and i got the code also for zip the folder [This is the link of that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11649468/creating-a-zip-file-from-a-folder-in-documents-directory-objective-c-arc)

ziping of folder is done perfectly but i am not able to unzip that. here is my code.

```
-(void)makeUnZip{
    NSString *stringPath1 = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *stringPath=[stringPath1 stringByAppendingPathComponent:[@"test" stringByAppendingFormat:@".zip"]];
    ZipFile *unzipFile = [[ZipFile alloc] initWithFileName:stringPath mode:ZipFileModeUnzip];
    NSArray *infos = [unzipFile listFileInZipInfos];
    for (NSString *file in infos) {

    ZipReadStream *readStream = [unzipFile readCurrentFileInZip];
    FileInZipInfo *fileInfo = [unzipFile getCurrentFileInZipInfo];
    NSString *fileName = [fileInfo name];


    NSLog(@"File Name--- %@",fileName);
    NSString *unzipFilePath = [stringPath1 stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

    NSString *dir = [unzipFilePath stringByDeletingLastPathComponent];
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:dir isDirectory:nil]) {
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:dir attributes:nil];
        NSLog(@"created directory %@", dir);
    }
    }

    [unzipFile close];
}
```

[This is link from where i got the reference for unzip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12813566/unzipping-a-zip-file-with-sub-folders-in-it-using-objective-zip)

NSLog shows only one file name for all the file and my ziped file of document directory is not unziping.

For example my zip folder contains 3 images abc1.png, abc2.png and abc3.png then NSLog shows abc3.png for all 3 and it is not unziping.

When i am unzipping manually by going to simulator folder then it is showing all the images perfectly.

Can any one look in too it and let me know where I am wrong ?

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6786835/how-to-unzip-folder-in-ios-iphone-application

Comment: Please goto this url..



http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11333399/download-and-unzip-file-in-ios

Comment: Thanks for answering. do you have any idea in objective-zip ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i have done it with [SSZipArchive](https://github.com/samsoffes/ssziparchive)

Not found enough help for objective-zip.
Thanks kirti mali and vijay to comment.